# Orientdb 2.1 http api load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, orientdb, haproxy

We're working on a service for mobile phones using orientdb.
Clients are the mobile phones that synchronize via a web service with the database.
Currently, exchanges between the web service and orientdb are written in php and use the http api.
Everything works fine, but we're now wondering how to scale up the system.
We're thinking about deploying a cluster behind a load balancer like haProxy.
Has anyone tested this solution ?
Is it working?
And what about performance and stability?